# Compiler throwing an error case label does not reduce to a constant

Tags: c, switch-statement

In my homework, I've been asked to write a program using both if and switch statement to compare the net amount paid by a customer for the following details

Purchase Amount (100-200) then give 5% Discount.

Purchase Amount (200-500) then give 7.5% Discount.

Purchase Amount (500-800) then give 10% Discount.

Purchase Amount (Above 1000) then give 15% Discount.

This is something I could come up with, but while compliling it is given me error like

Line 10: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
Line 13: error: case label does not reduce to an integer constant
Line 17: error: expected expression before ':' token. 
Can anyone please help me with this. Am I not following the question correctly or there is something else I'm doing wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int pa = 200;
 float net;
 printf("\n Enter purchased amount");
 scanf("%d",&pa);
 switch(pa)
 {
  case 1&&pa<=100:
     net=pa;
    break;
  case pa>=101&&pa<=200:    
        net=pa-(5.00/100.00)*pa;
    break;
 default:
         if(pa>=201&&pa<=500)
         net=pa-(7.5/100.00)*pa;
         if(pa>=501&&pa<=800)
         net=pa-(10.00/100.00)*pa;
         if(pa>=1000)
         net = pa - (15.00/100.00)*pa;
         break;

  }

  printf("\n the net amount to be paid is%f",net);
  getch();
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

`case` label should be compile time constant.

You cannot give a variable inside `case` label. Expression in label have to be evaluated at compile time.

If you want to branch during run time, use `if-else`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If case label does not need to be constant then How can it be possible to write this program using both if and switch statement? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: You want to write this program using both if and case?

Comment: Yes, That's what the question told me to.

Comment: Give me sometime, will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

if you use switch case, you must match against exact values (constants), otherwise,use cascaded if's

Just read how `switch`/`case` work

Answer (score 0):

For range related condition, it'd better to use if/else condition. switch/case is for constant value condition.

```
    if (pa >= 1 && pa <= 100) {
        net = pa;
     } else if (pa>=101&&pa<=200) {
       net=pa-(5.00/100.00)*pa;
     } else if (pa>=201&&pa<=500) {
       net=pa-(7.5/100.00)*pa;
     } else if (pa>=501&&pa<=800) {
       net=pa-(10.00/100.00)*pa;
     } else if (pa>=1000) {
       net = pa - (15.00/100.00)*pa;
     } else {`<br/>
       /* invalid pa handling */
     }
```